# Printing issue that only occurs for a specific number

Tags: python

This is my code :

```
def func(num1,num2):   
    print('%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s\n' %('DEC','BIN','OCT','HEX','ASCII'))   
    print('--'*40+'\n')   
    lis = xrange(num1,num2+1)   
    for i in lis:
    try:
      ascii = chr(i)
    except :
      ascii = None
    # print(i + '\t' + bin(i) + '\t' + oct(i) + 't' + hex(i) + ascii + '\n')
    print('debug : i is %d\n' % i)
    print("%-20d%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s\n" %(i,bin(i),oct(i),hex(i),ascii))
```

It is supposed to print out like this :

```
DEC                 BIN                 OCT                 HEX                 ASCII

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


1                   0b1                 01                  0x1


2                   0b10                02                  0x2
```

But, when i comes to 13, it just prints out this:

```
12                  0b1100              014                 0xc       



                    0b1101              015                 0xd                 

14                  0b1110              016                 0xe
```

Missing the Decimal digit of 13,why?

I have tried it on cygwin and pure linux , same result.
thanks.

Comment: Do you know what `chr(13)` is?

Comment: Great discovery today! Not all ASCII chars are printable. Chars 0…31 are control (non printable) characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the ascii 13 corresponds to `\r` , so when you print that , it returns the cursor back to the start of the line. Example -

```
>>> s = chr(13)
>>> repr(s)
"'\\r'"
```

And then the format you use - `%-20s` prints the `\r` at the start of the string and then 19 spaces, Example -

```
>>> '%-20s' % '\r'
'\r                   '
```

So, it overwrites 19 characters from the start of line with space, because of the `\r` character.

If what you want is to see what the corresponding ascii character is , which means most probably you need the internal representation of that character, then instead of printing `ascii` directly, you should print `repr(ascii)` , so that you get the correct internal representation of the string.